# php form checkbox search

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have created this php code for a search in a mysql database. However, I have problems with the checkboxes part. Without the checkbox part it works fine, but with it says "no data found". The part for the checkboxes is called tarif-typ.

`

```
    <?php

    include "db_connect.inc.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM praemien";
$sql .= " where kanton like '" . $_POST["kanton"] . "' and franchise = ". $_POST["franchise"] ." and ";

switch($_POST["unfall"])
{ case 1:
    $sql .="unfalleinschluss like 'OHN-UNF'";
    break;
 case 2:
    $sql .="unfalleinschluss like 'MIT-UNF'";
} 

$sql .=" and tarif-typ like '" . $_POST["tb"] . "' ";


$sql .= " order by praemie";

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($num==0) echo "Keine Datensätze gefunden";

while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
echo $dsatz["versicherungsnamen"] . ", "
    .$dsatz["kanton"] . ", "
    .$dsatz["tarif-typ"] . ", "
    .$dsatz["unfalleinschluss"] . ","
    . $dsatz["praemie"] . "<br />"; 

    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
</body>
```

`

and here is my html form

`

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action ="db_eingabe.php" method="post">
        <p><input name="kanton" /> Kanton</p>
        <p><input name="franchise" /> Franchise</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="unfall" value="1" checked="checked" />Unfall nein<br>
        <input type="radio" name="unfall" value="2" />Unfall ja</p>
        <br><p>
        <b>Tarif</b>
        </p>

    <p><input type="checkbox" name="tb1" value="TAR-BASE" checked="checked" />Grund</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="tb2" value="TAR-HMO" />HMO</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="tb3" value="TAR-HAM" />HAM</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="tb4" value="TAR-DIV" />andere</p>

        <p><input type="submit" /> 
        <input type ="reset" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Be careful with this code: like '" . $_POST["kanton"] . "', It is liable to sql injection. It is very dangerous for your server.

Comment: ok thanks. What do you think if the user can use from a dropdown menu is it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

starting another post to keep things clean...

your PHP code:

```
<?php

include "db_connect.inc.php";

$sql = "
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `praemien`
    WHERE
        `kanton` LIKE '" . $_POST["kanton"] . "'
        AND `franchise` = '". $_POST["franchise"] ."'
        AND `unfalleinschluss` LIKE '" . $_POST["unfall"] . "'";

$tbs = array();

foreach( array( 'tb1', 'tb2', 'tb3', 'tb4' ) as $tb_key )
{
    if ( empty( $_POST[$tb_key] ) ) continue;

    $tbs[] = "`tarif-typ` LIKE '" . $_POST[$tb_key] . "'";
}
if ( !empty( $tbs ) )
{
    $sql .= ' AND ( ' . implode( ' OR ', $tbs ) . ' )';
}
$sql .= " ORDER BY praemie";

echo $sql;

$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die( mysql_error() );
$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if ($num==0) echo "Keine Datensätze gefunden";

while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $dsatz["versicherungsnamen"] . ", "
    .$dsatz["kanton"] . ", "
    .$dsatz["tarif-typ"] . ", "
    .$dsatz["unfalleinschluss"] . ","
    . $dsatz["praemie"] . "<br />";
}
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

and your HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action ="db_eingabe.php" method="post">
    <p><input name="kanton" /> Kanton</p>
    <p><input name="franchise" /> Franchise</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="unfall" value="OHN-UNF" checked="checked" />Unfall nein<br>
    <input type="radio" name="unfall" value="MIT-UNF" />Unfall ja</p>
    <p>
    <b>Tarif</b>
    </p>

    <p><input type="checkbox" name="tb1" value="TAR-BASE" checked="checked" />Grund</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="tb2" value="TAR-HMO" />HMO</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="tb3" value="TAR-HAM" />HAM</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="tb4" value="TAR-DIV" />andere</p>

    <p><input type="submit" /> 
    <input type ="reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTES: fixed `franchise = '". $_POST["franchise"] ."'` -- it did not have single quotes

changed the `unfall` radio group to have specific values to avoid the `switch` you had

lastly, if the `tarif-typ` and `unfalleinschluss` columns only contain specific strings you have shown, you do not need `LIKE` you can use '=', however, if you want to find the strings IN the values, i suggest LIKE '%search_string%' with the % wildcards.

Comment: I tried again and now it works fine. Thanks a lot for your help. I did copy "order by" twice. I did it see in the echo. I was trying since yesterday to resolve it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think your checkboxes should be radios with all the same name (tb) because there is no field named "tb" submitted in your form and that is the reason why your query fails.

```
<p><input type="radio" name="tb" value="TAR-BASE" checked="checked" />Grund</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="tb" value="TAR-HMO" />HMO</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="tb" value="TAR-HAM" />HAM</p>
<p><input type="radio" name="tb" value="TAR-DIV" />andere</p>
```